# Induced matrix norm formula proof

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-norms

Suppose that $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ are equipped with norms $\|\cdot\|_b$ and $\|\cdot\|_a$ respectively.  Show that the induced matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_{a,b}$ can be computed by the formula

$$\|A\|_{a,b} = \max\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_b}{\|x\|_a}$$

and i use this definition for induced matrix

> [image]

can anyone answer this question?

Comment: Remind us what *definition* you are using for the induced matrix norm since the definition I am familiar with is the one you are trying to show equivalence to.

Comment: i add the description you asked for. (– JMoravitz)

Comment: welcome to MSE. you are encouraged to include thoughts and attempts if any.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_b }{\|x\|_a} = \left\| A\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|_a}\right)\right\|_b.
$$
Now, show that
$$
\begin{align*}
\max\left\{\frac{\|Ax\|_b}{\|x\|_a} : x \neq 0\right\}&= \max\{\|Ax\|_b : \|x\|_a = 1\} 
\\ & =  \max \{\|Ax\|_b: \|x\|_a \leq 1\} = \|A\|_{a,b}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: can i get more hint or the complete solution to this question?

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: oh i see. so in the first part since A is a linear transformation we can first divide x by it's magnitude and then do the linear transformation. and in the second part, in the first equality since the magnitude of x is equal to one, we could omit it but i don't get the next equality where max{∥Ax∥b:∥x∥a=1} = max{∥Ax∥b:∥x∥a≤1}

Comment: @mohsentajdeh Note that if $\|x\|<1$, then $\|Ax\|$ will never be equal to $\max\{\|Ax\|_b : \|x\|_a \leq 1\}$  since $\|A(x/\|x\|)\| > \|Ax\|$.